# Increment array index inside a for loop using OPENMP

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, openmp

I am new to openmp. I am trying to use openmp to parallelize nested loops with a array inside them. The array index is different than the loop indices. I have tried the following, but I have not been able to get correct results. Suggestions for parallelizing the following code are requested. Many Thanks

```
int iX, iY, iPart = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(iY) shared(iPart)      
for (iX = xStart; iX <= xEnd; iX++) {

            for (iY = yStart; iY <= yEnd; iY++) {

                    if (number[iX][iY].count > 0) {

                        int numCount = number[iX][iY].count;

                        for (int i = 0; i < numCount; i++) {

                            A[iPart] = B[number[iX][iY].list[i]];
                            #pragma omp atomic
                            iPart++;
                          }
                     }
             }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing to stop multiple threads updating the same element of `A`.  Wrapping `iPart++` in an `atomic` directive only means that each thread updates it atomically but does nothing to stop multiple threads reading the same value.  Imagine that all threads execute at exactly the same rate, then in the very first iteration all would update `A[0]` without any coordination.  You've programmed a *data race*.  That's no disgrace, anyone who has ever written a parallel program has done it.  I don't understand your code well enough to offer a fix.

Comment: The race may be avoided if it's possible to calculate iPart inside the parallel loop from the loop indices.  The conditional incrementing in the parallel loop appears to make this difficult.